# Transformar linhas em colunas com seus respectivos valores

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tenho a seguinte tabela

```
idRegistro|Campo |Valor
   1      |Nome  |Zonaro
   1      |Email |zonaro@outlook.com
   1      |campoX|valorX
   2      |Nome  |Fulano
   2      |tel   |1188889999
   2      |campoY|valorY
```

Preciso criar um select que retorne a coluna campo como o nome da coluna e todos os seus valores como resultado:

```
idRegistro|Nome  |Email             |campoX|tel       |campoY
   1      |Zonaro|zonaro@outlook.com|valorX|          |      
   2      |Fulano|                  |      |1188889999|valorY
```

Como devo proceder neste caso?

Comment: Poderia explicar melhor a sua dúvida?

Comment: Não sei como transformar os valores da coluna CAMPO em colunas e os valores da coluna VALOR em valores dessas colunas

Answer (score 12, accepted):

você deve fazer um PIVOT na sua tabela.

```
DECLARE @registros as table (
    idRegistro int,
    Campo varchar(50),
    Valor varchar(50)
)

INSERT INTO @registros VALUES (1, 'Nome', 'Zonaro');
INSERT INTO @registros VALUES (1, 'Email', 'zonaro@outlook.com');
INSERT INTO @registros VALUES (1, 'campoX', 'valorX');
INSERT INTO @registros VALUES (2, 'Nome', 'Fulano');
INSERT INTO @registros VALUES (2, 'tel', '1188889999');
INSERT INTO @registros VALUES (2, 'campoY', 'valorY');

SELECT * 
FROM @registros
PIVOT (
    MAX(Valor)
    FOR Campo IN
    ([Nome], [Email], [tel], [campoX], [campoY])
) AS pvt
ORDER BY idRegistro
```

porem para que funcione, você deve conhecer todas as colunas, no exemplo acima `([Nome], [Email], [tel], [campoX], [campoY])`.

caso conheça as colunas apenas em tempo de execução, pode montar a consulta dinamicamente, como no exemplo abaixo.

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);    
DECLARE @campos varchar(max)
SELECT 
    @campos = COALESCE(@campos + ', ', '') + '[' + Campo + ']'
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT Campo 
    FROM @registros
) campos

SELECT @sql = N'
    SELECT * 
    FROM @registros
    PIVOT (
        MAX(Valor)
        FOR Campo IN
        (' + @campos + ')
    ) AS pvt
    ORDER BY idRegistro
'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select * Into #Paises From _Países
```

é só substituir o * pelas colunas desejadas.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode esta fazendo dessa forma.

```
select idRegistro,Nome  ,Email             ,campoX,tel       ,campoY
INTO #tabelatemp from suatabela

select * from #tabelatemp
--where idRegistro = 1
```

[Mais detalhes aqui](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/advantage8.1/adssql/using_temporary_tables_in_sql_statements.htm)

Comment: Os campos se diferenciam para cada caso, horas terei 3 campos, horas terei 50. Preciso de uma forma de conseguir transformar todos os resultados em colunas

Comment: Use o `*`, mas uma coisa como você monta o select para que ele mude as colunas? é Pivot?

Comment: Nào monto, é justamente disso que preciso. Estou apanhando aqui com o pivot

Comment: Entendi. Mude sua pergunta para ficar mais clara, altere para. "Como altera linhas por colunas com Pivot" algo assim.