# Select com PIVOT sempre retorna null

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, pivot

Estou tentando fazer uma query utilizando o pivot baseado nesse link [inserir a descrição do link aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/113737/transformar-linhas-em-colunas-com-seus-respectivos-valores), porém sem sucesso, pois sempre retorna 2 linhas Nulas:

Query:

```
DECLARE @registros as table (
    ID  int,
    Campo varchar(250),
    Valor varchar(250)
)
INSERT INTO @registros VALUES
(1,'Pesquisar A','CRIAR'),
(1,'Pesquisar A','ATUALIZAR'),
(1,'Pesquisar A','DELETAR'),
(1,'Pesquisar A','PESQUISAR'),
(2,'Pesquisa B','CRIAR'),
(2,'Pesquisa B','ATUALIZAR')

SELECT * 
FROM @registros
PIVOT (
    MAX(Campo)
    FOR Valor IN
    ([NMFUNCIONALIDADE], [NMACOES])
) AS pvt
ORDER BY ID
```

Preciso que retorne assim:

```
|ID|Campo        |Valor  |Valor      |Valor    |Valor      |
|1 |'Pesquisar A'|'CRIAR'|'ATUALIZAR'|'DELETAR'|'PESQUISAR'|
|2 |'Pesquisar B'|'CRIAR'|'ATUALIZAR'|NULL     |NULL       |
```

No entanto sempre retorna Null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa alterar as colunas a serem pesquisadas dentro do *pivot*:

```
DECLARE @registros as table (
    ID  int,
    Campo varchar(250),
    Valor varchar(250)
)
INSERT INTO @registros VALUES
(1,'Pesquisar A','CRIAR'),
(1,'Pesquisar A','ATUALIZAR'),
(1,'Pesquisar A','DELETAR'),
(1,'Pesquisar A','PESQUISAR'),
(2,'Pesquisa B','CRIAR'),
(2,'Pesquisa B','ATUALIZAR')

SELECT * 
FROM @registros
PIVOT (
    MAX(Campo)
    FOR Valor IN
    ([CRIAR], [ATUALIZAR], [DELETAR], [PESQUISAR])
) AS pvt
ORDER BY ID
```

Dá uma olhada no [*fiddle*](https://rextester.com/WBSRM15798).