# Linhas em Colunas sem Predefinição de colunas - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Ola, estou com uma dificuldade transformar linhas em colunas no `SQL Server`.

Não consegui escrever nada ainda... Pensei no `PIVOT`, mas como não é sempre a mesma quantidade de colunas, não estou conseguindo pensar em como fazer...

Tenho essas 2 tabelas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Resultado esperado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> É para um relatório isso.

Comment: Que tal uma function ou uma subConsulta?

Comment: @Marconi, como faria? O meu maior problema está sendo em, eu nao ter uma quantidade definida de colunas, ou seja, neste exemplo eu fiz com 4 defeitos, mas eu posso ter mais, tanto quanto eu posso ter menos

Comment: Como se eu tivesse um contador que me mostrasse o item que tem mais defeito e este seria o meu limite para aquele relatorio, seguindo entao, eu terias os demais itens com seus respectivos defeitos. Ou seja, se o item com a maior quantidade de defeitos for 5, entao terei 5 colunas de defeitos e assim, os demais defeitos de cada item, seria distribuido nestas 5 colunas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leooso, você precisa fazer um PIVOT em cima de um INNER JOIN, seria algo assim... exemplo

```
SELECT equ.Id, equ.Equipamento, def.*
FROM equipamento equ
INNER JOIN defeito def
ON equ.Id = def.EquipamentoID
```

Agora o PIVOT:

```
DECLARE @registros as table (
    id int,
    equipamento varchar(50),
    Defeito1 varchar(50),
    Defeito2 varchar(50),
    Defeito3 varchar(50),
    Defeito4 varchar(50)
)

SELECT * 
FROM @registros
PIVOT (
    MAX(Valor)
    FOR Campo IN
    ([Nome], [Email], [tel], [campoX], [campoY])
) AS pvt
ORDER BY idRegistro
```

Veja também:

[Transformar linhas em colunas com seus respectivos valores](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/113737/transformar-linhas-em-colunas-com-seus-respectivos-valores)

Comment: Mas eu nao tenho uma quantidade exata de defeitos entendeu? Assim como posso ter 5 posso ter 20, pode ser que eu nao esteja conseguindo visualizar a sua solução

Comment: Dando uma melhor analisada eu entendi a sua solução, porem eu não posso ter fixo esses seguintes valores: (No meu caso) `([Defeito 1],[Defeito 2],[Defeito 3],[Defeito 4])` pq eu não sei quantos podem vir a existir...

Comment: Leo, veja o link que eu te passei (Transformar linhas em colunas com seus respectivos valores) pq o camarada fez com um número variável de colunas também, do jeito que você quer.

Comment: Perdão, não tinha reparado, vou dar uma olhada

Comment: Mais uma vez desculpa por não ter prestado atenção, deu certo aqui, obrigado